# How to name parameters of F# function declaration

Tags: f#

If I've got a record type that contains all the database functions like so

```
type Database =
  { getThingsByCountThenLength: int -> int -> Thing list
    getUsersByFirstNameThenLastName: string -> string -> User list }
```

Is there any way to name the input parameters, so it's more clear?  Something like the following (which doesn't compile)

```
type Database =
  { getThings: count:int -> length:int -> Thing list
    getUsers: firstName:string -> lastName:string -> User list }
```

(Note it *does* work for interfaces; I just want it for records.)

```
type IDatabase =
  abstract getThings: count:int -> length:int -> Thing list
  abstract getUsers: firstName:string -> lastName:string -> User list
```

Comment: Use a record for the arguments?

Comment: @JohnPalmer That's probably what I'll do, but records don't support my currying addiction.  (Though that'd be another good argument for structural typing—it'd allow you use records *and* curry the parameters (I think)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a direct answer (I don't think there is one), but as an alternative you can use [single-case union types](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-single-case-dus/), which will not only add clarity and continue to allow currying, but also enforce compile-time correctness.

```
type Count = Count of int
type Length = Length of int
type FirstName = FirstName of string
type LastName = LastName of string

type Database =
  { getThings: Count -> Length -> Thing list
    getUsers: FirstName -> LastName -> User list }
```

Answer (score 3):

Type aliases might be what you want:

```
type count = int
type length = int
type firstName = string
type lastName = string

type Database =
  { getThings: count -> length -> Thing list
    getUsers: firstName -> lastName -> User list }
```

Though, in this case, they look rather weird

---

Other option is using a record instead

```
type whatever = {
  count : int;
  length : int;
}

let param = { count = 1; length = 1; }

param |> printfn "%A"
```

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned, I don't think you can name parameters of a function inside a record.

However, you can name parameters of members inside an interface. If you were happy with using an interface, then you could write something like this:

```
type IDatabase =
  abstract GetThingsByCountThenLength : 
    count:int -> length:int -> Thing list
  abstract GetUsersByFirstNameThenLastName : 
    firstName:string -> lastName:string -> User list
```

For types that are used across multiple files, I generally prefer to follow the .NET coding style for this and so I would probably choose an interface - unless there are some good reasons for choosing a record. However, this is certainly a matter of personal preference & style.

Comment: If you go with the interface, is it more typical in F# to stick with OOP style there and tuple the parameters, or to leave them curried (curryable? is there a name for that?)?

Comment: I've seen and used both styles. In general I only use tupled parameters if I want to have overloaded methods, or to provide "fluent" style (methods that return `this` to be chained).